# reactstrap install from github

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, reactstrap

I want the latest commit in reactstrap in my react/redux app. I have added it to my package.json as so:

```
"dependencies": {
      "reactstrap": "git@github.com:reactstrap/reactstrap.git#24951541a110451c167ff53e6ebb367972717bc5",
}
```

It seems to install fine but when I start my dev server with npm start, I am getting the following errors:

```
 Module not found: 'reactstrap' in /myapp/src/views/Scans
```

Is there anything special I need to do to install it this way and have it included properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at the [docs](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap) for `reactstrap`.

Did you follow the installation instructions and install `bootstrap` as well?

```
npm install --save bootstrap
npm install --save reactstrap
```